# Rotated HTML Text-Inputs with CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, input, flexbox, css-transforms

There are labels on my web page that are arranged by the following pattern:
The main container `content` contains `rows`. A row has two `labels` in it and a single `label` contains three `columns`. Each `column` can contain one or more `input["text"]` elements.

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    resize: vertical;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: none;                                       
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: ease-in-out, width .35s ease-in-out;
}
                                                                                                                                    
input:hover, input:focus {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    background-color: #baffc9;                                                                                                      
    border-radius: 3px;                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                    
.label-row {                                                                                                                        
    height: 3.0cm;                                                                                                                  
    width: 18.8cm;                                                                                                                  
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    flex-grow: 0;                                                                                                                   
    flex-wrap: nowrap;                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.label {                                                                                                                            
    border: 1px dashed black;                                                                                                       
    width: 9.4cm;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    flex-wrap: nowrap;                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.col-left {                                                                                                                         
    width: 4.4cm;                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                   
.col-middle {                                                                                                                       
    width: 1.0cm;                                                                                                                   
    border-left: 1px dotted black;                                                                                                  
    border-right: 1px dotted black;                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
.col-right {                                                                                                                        
    width: 4.0cm;                                                                                                                   
}           
                                                                       
/* ----- column-left ----- */                                                                                                       
.hsig-wrapper {                                                                                                                     
    flex-direction: column;                                                                                                         
    justify-content: space-evenly;                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.hl {                                                                                                                               
    font-size: 10px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.sk {                                                                                                                               
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.format {                                                                                                                           
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.hsig {                                                                                                                             
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.sig_add {                                                                                                                          
    font-size: 10px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
/* ----- column-middle ----- */                                                                                                     
.loc-wrapper {                                                                                                                      
    background-color: transparent;                                                                                                  
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    height: 100%;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    text-align: center;                                                                                                             
    justify-content: center;                                                                                                        
    align-items: center;                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.loc {                                                                                                                              
    font-size: 20px;                                                                                                                
    width: 2.9cm;                                                                                                                   
    height: 0.9cm;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                              
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                   
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
}

/* ----- column-right ----- */                                                                                                      
.as-wrapper {                                                                                                                       
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    height: 100%;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    text-align: center;                                                                                                             
    justify-content: center;                                                                                                        
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    align-items: center;                                                                                                            
    /*flex-wrap: nowrap;*/                                                                                                          
    /*justify-content: space-evenly;*/                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.as_detail {                                                                                                                        
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    align-self: center;                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                    
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
    width: 0.8cm;                                                                                                                   
    /*height: 30%;*/                                                                                                                                                                                      
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                              
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                   
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div class="label-row">

  <div class="label">
    <div class="col-left">
      <div class="hsig-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="hl"
                          id="hl"
                          name="hl"
                          value="Headline">
        <input type="text" class="format"
                          id="format"
                          name="format"
                          value="II">
        <input type="text" class="hsig"
                           id="hsig"
                           name="hsig"
                           value="12 345">
        <input type="text" class="sig_add"
                           id="sig_add"
                           name="sig_add"
                           value="Detail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-middle">
        <div class="loc-wrapper"> 
          <input type="text" class="loc"
                             id="loc"
                             name="loc"
                             value="ABC">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-right">
        <div class="as-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_0"
                             name="as_detail_0"
                             value="1">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_1"                                                                                
                             name="as_detail_1"
                             value="2">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_2"
                             name="as_detail_2"                                                                                
                             value="3">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_3"
                             name="as_detail_3"
                             value="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
                                                                                              
</div>
```

On [liveweave](https://liveweave.com/fjmdqy) is almost the whole problem pictured.

**The Problem:**

- The only column that is working is col-middle.
- The left ignores the `justify-content: space-evenly;`. The input-text boxes do not use the bottom space: I could not push the `Detail` down to the line.
- In the col-right I could rotate the input-text boxes, but their size is too small. I wanted to align them in the middle of the label (like the `loc` `ABC`), but they won't move down. Every time when I tried to increase their width (from 0.8cm to 0.9cm), the alignment was destroyed.

What can I do in these cases? Is my flexbox model to complicated or even built up totally wrong? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I made the following changes to your code:

1. Made `hsig-wrapper` a full-width *flexbox* and the first column is sorted out.
2. Flex items *shrink* only as much as its content as `min-width` is *auto* by default - so set `min-width: 0` to `as_detail` element.

See demo below:

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  resize: vertical;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out, width .35s ease-in-out;
}

input:hover,
input:focus {
  background-color: #baffc9;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.label-row {
  height: 3.0cm;
  width: 18.8cm;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.label {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 9.4cm;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.col-left {
  width: 4.4cm;
}

.col-middle {
  width: 1.0cm;
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
}

.col-right {
  width: 4.0cm;
}


/* ----- column-left ----- */

.hsig-wrapper {
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  height: 100%; /* ADDED */
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.hl {
  font-size: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.sk {
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.format {
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.hsig {
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.sig_add {
  font-size: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


/* ----- column-middle ----- */

.loc-wrapper {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loc {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 2.9cm;
  height: 0.9cm;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


/* ----- column-right ----- */

.as-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  /*flex-wrap: nowrap;*/
  /*justify-content: space-evenly;*/
}

.as_detail {
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 0.8cm;
  /*height: 30%;*/
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <div class="label-row">

    <div class="label">
      <div class="col-left">
        <div class="hsig-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="hl" id="hl" name="hl" value="Headline">
          <input type="text" class="format" id="format" name="format" value="II">
          <input type="text" class="hsig" id="hsig" name="hsig" value="12 345">
          <input type="text" class="sig_add" id="sig_add" name="sig_add" value="Detail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-middle">
        <div class="loc-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="loc" id="loc" name="loc" value="ABC">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-right">
        <div class="as-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail" id="as_detail_0" name="as_detail_0" value="1">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail" id="as_detail_1" name="as_detail_1" value="2">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail" id="as_detail_2" name="as_detail_2" value="3">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail" id="as_detail_3" name="as_detail_3" value="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: wow, it looks great :) thanks! That's exactly how I wanted to do `col-left` and almost what I had in mind for `col-right`: the text-alignment is perfect; do you have any ideas if values of `as_detail` will be longer than 1 digit, e.g. `Hand-1.2`?

Comment: tried using wrappers for the `as-detail` input boxes - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RYYqYX

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    resize: vertical;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: none;                                       
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: ease-in-out, width .35s ease-in-out;
}
                                                                                                                                    
input:hover, input:focus {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    background-color: #baffc9;                                                                                                      
    border-radius: 3px;                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                    
.label-row {                                                                                                                        
    height: 3.0cm;                                                                                                                  
    width: 18.8cm;                                                                                                                  
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    flex-grow: 0;                                                                                                                   
    flex-wrap: nowrap;                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.label {                                                                                                                            
    border: 1px dashed black;                                                                                                       
    width: 9.4cm;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    flex-wrap: nowrap;                                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.col-left {                                                                                                                         
    width: 4.4cm;                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                   
.col-middle {                                                                                                                       
    width: 1.0cm;                                                                                                                   
    border-left: 1px dotted black;                                                                                                  
    border-right: 1px dotted black;                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
.col-right {                                                                                                                        
    width: 4.0cm;                                                                                                                   
}           
                                                                       
/* ----- column-left ----- */                                                                                                       
.hsig-wrapper {                                                                                                                     
    flex-direction: column;                                                                                                         
    justify-content: space-evenly;                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.hl {                                                                                                                               
    font-size: 10px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.sk {                                                                                                                               
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.format {                                                                                                                           
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.hsig {                                                                                                                             
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.sig_add {                                                                                                                          
    font-size: 10px;                                                                                                                
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
/* ----- column-middle ----- */                                                                                                     
.loc-wrapper {                                                                                                                      
    background-color: transparent;                                                                                                  
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    height: 100%;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    text-align: center;                                                                                                             
    justify-content: center;                                                                                                        
    align-items: center;                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.loc {                                                                                                                              
    font-size: 20px;                                                                                                                
    width: 2.9cm;                                                                                                                   
    height: 0.9cm;                                                                                                                                                                                        
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                              
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                   
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
}

/* ----- column-right ----- */                                                                                                      
.as-wrapper {                                                                                                                       
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    height: 100%;                                                                                                                   
    display: flex;                                                                                                                  
    text-align: center;                                                                                                             
    justify-content: center;                                                                                                        
    flex-direction: row;                                                                                                            
    align-items: center;                                                                                                            
    /*flex-wrap: nowrap;*/                                                                                                          
    /*justify-content: space-evenly;*/                                                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                    
.as_detail {                                                                                                                        
    font-size: 18px;                                                                                                                
    width: 100%;                                                                                                                    
    align-self: center;                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                    
    flex: 0 1 auto;                                                                                                                 
    width: 0.8cm;                                                                                                                   
    /*height: 30%;*/                                                                                                                                                                                      
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                              
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);                                                                                                   
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

<div class="label-row">

  <div class="label">
    <div class="col-left">
      <div class="hsig-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="hl"
                          id="hl"
                          name="hl"
                          value="Headline">
        <input type="text" class="format"
                          id="format"
                          name="format"
                          value="II">
        <input type="text" class="hsig"
                           id="hsig"
                           name="hsig"
                           value="12 345">
        <input type="text" class="sig_add"
                           id="sig_add"
                           name="sig_add"
                           value="Detail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-middle">
        <div class="loc-wrapper"> 
          <input type="text" class="loc"
                             id="loc"
                             name="loc"
                             value="ABC">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-right">
        <div class="as-wrapper">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_0"
                             name="as_detail_0"
                             value="1">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_1"                                                                                
                             name="as_detail_1"
                             value="2">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_2"
                             name="as_detail_2"                                                                                
                             value="3">
          <input type="text" class="as_detail"
                             id="as_detail_3"
                             name="as_detail_3"
                             value="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
                                                                                              
</div>
```